# Not found bootstrap.css when using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem [Rails3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I would like to use less with twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, but i receiving "Failed to load /assets/bootstrap.css" and "Failed to load /assets/bootstrap-responsive.css" errors (safari web inspector). Any ideas?

Here is my **Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'roo'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'less-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'angularjs-rails'
  gem 'angular-ui-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'

  gem 'slim'

  gem 'sass-rails'

  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rabl'
gem 'yajl-ruby'

group :production do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "rvm-capistrano"
  gem 'ruby-prof'
end
```

Here is my **bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less** file:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
// Note: If you use asset_path() here, your compiled bootstrap_and_overrides.css will not
//       have the proper paths. So for now we use the absolute path.
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.svg");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome";

// Glyphicons
@import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;

.icon-pressed {
  .icon-white;
  .label;
  width: auto
}

table > thead th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: 50% !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is my **application.css**:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require daterangepicker
 *= require bootstrap-timepicker
 *= require angular-ui
 *= require_tree .
 */
body { padding-top: 50px; }
footer { margin-top: 200px; }
```

Here is my **view**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form class="form-search">
  <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the command

```
rake assets:precompile
```

so the [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) files get copied into public folder. Try that, otherwise it may be that you are not adding the CSS to your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I've precompiled assets, but there is no css files in public/twitter/bootstrap folder. There are only glyphicons files

Comment: I ran this and I still have no bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you just to add a new insertion to your `application.css` manifest file . You should add :

```
*= require bootstrap 
*= require bootstrap-responsive
```

right after `*=require self` statement . I think it is a part of installing the gem `twitter-bootstrap-rails` , which means that you have missed `rails g bootstrap:install` .

The error messages are generated from wrong inclusion on the top of your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file` (`@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";`
). You should remove them .

You may consider to get more information from [this RialsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast).

Comment: Where did you place the view ? If you would like to try if the gem works , generate a dummy scaffold (`rails g scaffold Project name content:text`). Then go to localhost:3000/projects .

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found it!
I forget to delete these lines

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive" %>
```

from my application.html.erb